# Control commands of the Onboard-SDK are published with different frequencies

Tags: dji-sdk

I am using the Onboard-SDK for DJI M100 on ROS.
I developed a code for controlling the position of the M100 to certain target position.
However, it doesn't reach the specified target.
For that reason I checked the published control signals with ROS, and as I saw, in some experiments the frequency of the control signal is not "constant" at all. For example, sometimes I have 50Hz, some others 5Hz, 10Hz etc.
I would like to know what is the actual reason behind this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you 3.3V FTDI works and have perfect working hardware, I would guess some 1 changed the DJI assistant2 SDK setting for you. Otherwise, it will not changes. I had some simar problem before, but the problem is I burn the API port by using 5V FTDI

Besides, you control should be sent to the drone in a fixed time loop by running a ros loop rate and ros sleep routing. not send at each callback. The reason being that you need to control your drone position with PID or other control methods which is time depended.

Comment: I think that my hardware is working properly.
I agree on what you say regarding the control loop. However, the example of position control in Onboard-SDK, applies the control every measurement callback.

Comment: Just rewrite it. takes less than 10 min to do so.  If you want I can give you my changed template for local position control

Comment: Yes, that would be great. Just to be sure that we understood the same!